# keydown not firing Chrome on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following code - it's got some temporary alerts in at the moment as I'm trying to get to the bottom of this issue.

The functionality is based around an Asp.Net Textbox and a RequiredFieldValidator. The idea being that when 'enter' is pressed I get the status of the textbox and do something.

Now, here's the strange bits:

If I use a standard type="text" on the textbox - I don't actually add this its just defaulted, it works on all browsers/devices.

By works, I mean if I don't put a valid entry i.e. anything in the textbox, an error should display.

If I use type="tel" or type="number", it works on Firefox and Chrome desktop but not Chrome on mobile.

If I add the alerts in as per the code below, mobile works too.

```
function enterKeyPressed(e) {
        alert("function called");
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert("enter pressed");
            var isValid = updateInputState.call(this, false);
            alert(isValid);
            if (isValid) {
                var next = findNextTabStop.call(this);
                next.focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone got any idea where I can start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me - desktop, mobile and all html5 input types.

```
function enterKeyPressed(e) {
        if (e.which == "13") {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which):

```
function enterKeyPressed(e) {
  alert("function called");
      if (e.key == "Enter") {
        alert("enter pressed");
        var isValid = updateInputState.call(this, false);
        alert(isValid);
        if (isValid) {
            var next = findNextTabStop.call(this);
            next.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very odd - if I remove the type = "tel", it works.

Comment: Seem to be getting to the bottom of this - the 'enter' key for the numeric keypad is 9 not 13!!!